# Do I need to care for request collisions on server in multi user application

Tags: c#, wpf, collision, multi-user

I am trying to create a multi-user application that is connected to a centralized database in server, the question is in my application do I need to consider collisions? if tow clients make a transaction at a time.
or  it would handled by the server it self?
thanks in advance

Comment: As it stands the question is too broad - what specifically are you concerned about?  Do you use session/application/cache variables?  Are your updates atomic or at least in one transaction?

Comment: This question is indeed too broad to provide a good answer. In the general case, any concurrent multi-client system will need to address the trade-off between Consistency, Availability and Partition tolerance (google "CAP theorem"). If you have a centralized database server, it appears these trade-off decisions have already been made for you. You should learn what they are, whether they are ok for your application, how they could impact it and how you are going to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what a centralized database does.  It (correctly) manages concurrent updates.